# OpenSSL Configuration for Ubuntu 20.04 LAMP& WP Multisites

Tags: openssl, wordpress-mu

**Question:**  How do I apply 1 OpenSSL certificate to all websites located in html directory?
**Problem:** When visiting `https://localhost.site1.com` or `https://localhost.site2.com` only `index.html` located at `/var/www/html/index.html` is displayed because `default-ssl.conf` document root is /var/www/html/

I have 2 wordpress multisites (and other sites) located in `/var/www/html/`:

`/var/www/html/site1.com`

and

`/var/www/html/site2.com`

In my `default-ssl.conf` I have:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin info@dummy.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
      BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

In my `/etc/hosts` file I have:

```
127.0.1.1   excalibur
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.0.1   localhost.site1.com *.localhost.site1.com   # mainsite url
127.0.0.1   subsite-a.localhost.site1.com   
127.0.0.1   subsite-b.localhost.site1.com
127.0.0.1   subsite-c.localhost.site1.com

127.0.0.1   localhost.site2.com *.localhost.site2.com   # mainsite url
```

The vhost for site1.com contains:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost.site1.com 
    ServerAlias www.localhost.site1.com
    
    # If this is the default configuration file we can use: 'ServerName localhost' or also 'ServerAlias localhost'.

    ServerAdmin info@dummy.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.site1.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.site1.com.access.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.com
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/site1.com>
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/site1.com/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
    
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

</VirtualHost>
```

And the vhost for site2.com contains:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost.site2.com
    ServerAlias www.localhost.site2.com
    
    # If this is the default configuration file we can use: 'ServerName localhost' or also 'ServerAlias localhost'.

    ServerAdmin info@dummy.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.site2.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.site2.com.access.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2.com
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/site2.com>
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/site2.com/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
   
</VirtualHost>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual hosts are listening on port 80, while a HTTPS connection uses port 443. For this, you get served with what is in the default SSL config, since that is the only config for port 443.

Changing your `VirtualHost` definitions to `<VirtualHost *:443>` will probably solve the issue.

Comment: thx... worked like a charm